# Not able to understand Binary Search Tree Delete

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I was trying to understand BST from this link [BinarySearchTree](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-binary-search-tree/). But i have got confused in the else part

```
 /* Functions to delete data */
 public void delete(int k)
 {
     if (isEmpty())
         System.out.println("Tree Empty");
     else if (search(k) == false)
         System.out.println("Sorry "+ k +" is not present");
     else
     {
         root = delete(root, k);
         System.out.println(k+ " deleted from the tree");
     }
 }
 private BSTNode delete(BSTNode root, int k)
 {
     BSTNode p, p2, n;
     if (root.getData() == k)
     {
         BSTNode lt, rt;
         lt = root.getLeft();
         rt = root.getRight();
         if (lt == null && rt == null)
             return null;
         else if (lt == null)
         {
             p = rt;
             return p;
         }
         else if (rt == null)
         {
             p = lt;
             return p;
         }
         else
         {
             p2 = rt;
             p = rt;
             while (p.getLeft() != null)
               p = p.getLeft();
             p.setLeft(lt);
             return p2;
         }
     }
     if (k < root.getData())
     {
         n = delete(root.getLeft(), k);
         root.setLeft(n);
     }
     else
     {
         n = delete(root.getRight(), k);
         root.setRight(n);             
     }
     return root;
 }
```

I am not able to understand else part where left most node of right sub tree is found and then assigned to the node.
But here neither that node is made null and right node is returned which is not making sense to me. I am hoping this is a correct implementation.
Can someone help me in understanding whats is happening here.

Comment: In your code isempty() is not defined. So what does it do?

Comment: @Marichyasana I think we can safely assume that it checks if the tree is empty. Not really relevant to understanding or answering the question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last else block in this code covers the case of deleting a node with two children.

What the code seems to do is:

- finding the in-order successor node (i.e. the leftmost node in the right subtree)
- appending the whole original left subtree to this node
- returning the original right child as the new root of the tree

Although this iterative implementation seems correct to me, I guess that after a few delete operations you end up with an unbalanced tree.

A [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion) implementation of the delete operation, although harder to understand at first, is usually more elegant to read.

Answer (score 0):

The key concept is that you're talking about *Binary Search Tree*. As you know, BST are ordered structues, which means that for every tree the elements contained in the left sub-tree are all minor or equals to the tree root.